# Recursive decimal to binary converter in python

Tags: python, recursion, binary

```
def toBinary(decimal, binaryList):
    if decimal <= 1:
        return binaryList
    else:
        decimal = decimal //2
        return toBinary(decimal, binaryList)
        binaryList.append(decimal %2)
```

The functions returns empty brackets instead of printing the binary number as a list.

Comment: The last line will never be executed.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is on the right track but has issues.  First is what @KlausD comments, no line directly after a `return` gets executed.  So the order of statements is at issue.  Next, the variable `binaryList` doesn't get initialized in your provided code fragment.  It could get initialized by the caller:

```
array = toBinary(13, []):
```

which works, but the caller might find it strange.  We could intialize it using a default:

```
def toBinary(13, binaryList=[]):
```

But as a container type, that would constitute a *dangerous default* which we want to steer clear of.  We could safely initialize it to `None` as a default and reinitialize it later in the code:

```
def toBinary(decimal, binaryList=None):
    # ...
    if binaryList is None:
        binaryList = []
```

Which is safe and hides this argument from the caller.  Next, by dividing, we're analyzing our decimal digits from *right to left*, so we need to build up our binary number in the same direction, thus `append()`:

```
binaryList.append(decimal % 2)
```

is a problem as it builds up the binary result from *left to right*.  We could end with a `revese()` but it's probably better to use `binaryList.insert(0, ...)` to build in the proper direction.  Finally, this is a special case:

```
array = toBinary(0)
```

as we're going to use a zero argument to trigger end of recursion but how it affects our result (i.e. not at all) is different than if we're passed zero from the get-go (i.e. return a `[0]`).  Here's my rework of your code that addresses all of these issues:

```
def toBinary(decimal, binaryList=None):

    if decimal == 0:
            return binaryList or [0]

    if binaryList is None:
        binaryList = []

    binaryList.insert(0, decimal % 2)

    return toBinary(decimal // 2, binaryList)

print(toBinary(13))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
> python3 test.py
[1, 1, 0, 1]
>
```

Comment: Passing in a list to start will still cause issues if the function is called with an actual list - having an internal recursive function and an outer non-recursive function would solve this. (all this ignoring `list(map(int,bin(decimal)[2:]))` of course, assuming the OP really needs to learn about recursive functions and is farming this out to SO...)

Answer (score 0):

It is better not to return binary list.

```
def toBinary(decimal, binaryList):
    if decimal <= 0:
        return
    else:
        toBinary(decimal//2, binaryList)
        binaryList.append(decimal %2)
```

Answer (score 0):

This code also converts to Binary. It can also convert into other bases. Just change the parameter base, to the base you want.

```
import string

def to_base(value, base=2): # converts decimal to base n

    string_slice = string.printable[0:base]
    data_dict = {}
    for each_character, each_number in zip(string_slice, range(base)):
        data_dict.update({each_character: each_number})

    data = []
    temporary_var = value
    data.append(temporary_var)

    while True:
        temporary_var = temporary_var // base
        data.append(temporary_var)
        if temporary_var < base:
            break
        else:
            continue

    result = ''
    for each_data in data:
        result += list(data_dict.keys())[each_data % base]
    result = result[::-1]
    return result by
```

My code may not be perfect. Feel free to suggest improvements.

```
print(to_base(5, base=2))   # Outputs : 101.   Because 101 is 5 in binary
print(to_base(17, base=16))    # Outputs : 11.  Because 11 is 17 in hexadecimal
```